# Group by and Order by detailed execution in JPA with coalesce

Tags: spring, oracle, jpa, criteria

Is there any difference in the way coalesce is handled for group by and order by?

I have a criteria query which does the following
selects, orders and groups the column with a coalesce(column, "string")

When the criteria query is translated to SQL, I notice the following

```
select coalesce(column, "string"), group by coalesce(column, "string") but order by coalesce(column, ?) param.
```

It is using string literals for select and group while using placeholder for parameter binding for order by.

Comment: In Oracle something which is double-quoted is not a string literal, it's a case-sensitive identifier name.